# how to show url images objects in forms.py

Tags: django

## ican't view image

how can show image in template using  crispy_forms.layout html
this code don't do this 
 img  is Empty

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, html, div

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):           
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        
        Div(
            HTML("""
             <img src="{{image.value.url}}" class="card-img-top" width="50px" height="100px" alt="...">
        """),
)

  }
```

please how can fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fixed**

After I tried, I finally found the solution, I called the path, and when I called the path, the name of the folder containing the images was missing, and I wrote it manually, and so the operation was successful.

```
HTML("""{% if form.image.value %}
            <img class="img-responsive col-md-6" style="width:40%"
            src="/media/{{ form.image.value }}">{% endif %}"""),
```

you can change /media/ to {{MEDIA_ROOT}}

Comment: @CodeView- Hardcoding path is not a good practise. "/media/...." - A big no

Answer (score 1):

@Codeview- This is how I would do.
Let's say in my models.py there is a field called

```
image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
```

Then in my template and I am using crispy forms

```
 <a href="{{ object.image_one.url }}" data-toggle="lightbox"
                                       data-title="sample 1 - white">
```

Also need to make sure that your static URLs are loaded properly
main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = (
    [url(r"^ecommerce/", include(main))]
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
)
```

Comment: in template    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% crispy form %} وCreate the complete design process across forms.py